# How to have SetInterval() in $.when function

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, getjson, .when

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56212157/how-to-run-get-json-and-save-as-a-variable-then-use-it-in-other-methods/56212457#56212457).

I have a set of funtions that has to run one after another. The first function (`$.when()`)starts when 2 JSON files are parsed from external links. However, I would like the parse the JSON files once every second. This is where I stuck. 
Here is a sample of my code:

```js
var myJSON;

function _parseJSON() {
  // return here, no need returning exactly what you would expect anyhow
  return $.getJSON(settings.json_src);
}

// because you returned, you can chain everything nicely together
$.when( _parseJSON() )
  // don't forget the argument here
  .then(function( data ) { myJSON = data; })
  // and these will only run after the myJSON got set
  .then( _cacheOptions )
  .then( _cacheDom )
  .then( _events )
  .then( _render );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I want `_parseJSON()` to be called every second to get the latest data. Then based on the result of that, `_cacheOptions` and `_render` functions will get updated.

I know I should use set intervals for this, but I dont know how to implement that. 
If it is possible I prefer only the mentioned functions get updated every second, It would be too heavy to update the all functions.

Any suggestions would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write the same update code inside a `setInterval` block and add it below to your code:

```
// because you returned, you can chain everything nicely together
$.when( _parseJSON() )
  // don't forget the argument here
  .then(function( data ) { myJSON = data; })
  // and these will only run after the myJSON got set
  .then( _cacheOptions )
  .then( _cacheDom )
  .then( _events )
  .then( _render );

var intervalId = setInterval(function(){

  // below will start after a second and hereafter execute every second!

  $.when( _parseJSON() )
    .then(function( data ) { myJSON = data; })
    .then( _cacheOptions )
    .then( _render );

}, 1000)
```

Later, you can cancel these repetitive executions when you need it.

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

However, executing an HTTP request on every second in an internet environment is not a proper way that can cause a heavy burden for clients as I think. 5 or 10 seconds according to your needs would be ideal. I hope it helps. Cheers!